# how to make jQuery .resize() function trigger only when the div actually resizes to grid?

Tags: jquery

When you snap resizable to a grid like in the example below you get the .resize() function triggered for every pixel you drag your mouse.

```
$("#box").resizable({grid:[50,50]);
$("#box").resize(function(){
    var w = $(this).width();
    var h = $(this).height();
}
```

How to make it so it triggers only when the size of the div actually changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

[jQuery resizable doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#event-stop)